# using three.js for a randomly animating element from a grid

Tags: three.js

I need to create a grid, let's say a photo gallery and to be able to animate an element randomly as the user lands on page .

I am completely new to three.js and could not find a relevant example. Can someone point me to one please?

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, Three.js is used for rendering 3D objects in WebGL, not HTML elements.

If you simply want to animate HTML elements (e.g., photos in a gallery), you might be better off using Javascript or CSS Animations.

Here's a good start, a whole library of predefined CSS Animations:
https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be very helpful for your case:
[image-gallery-threejs](https://github.com/blockhead123/image-gallery-threejs)

you can watch a live demo [here](http://image-gallery-threejs.zholpe.com)

This is just for creating a photo gallery. I would recommend you to setup your scene first and then start looking at the animation you need.